# High-side switching: Load switch IC vs P-channel MOSFET

Tags: circuit-design, switches, battery-operated, component-selection

I want to switch the power in one part of a circuit with a 3V0 GPIO. The circuit is battery-powered and only active for a short duration once an hour, so I want to use as little power as possible. The maximum current consumption of the circuit is roughly 60-70mA.

The switch will be on the high side, so I've been thinking of using a load switch IC or a P-channel MOSFET. In general, which  solution is preferred when we want to minimize quiescent and leakage current?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The switch will be on the high side, so I've been thinking of using a load switch IC or a P-channel MOSFET. In general, which solution is preferred when we want to minimize quiescent and leakage current?

There's neither a general solution nor a general preference. All depend on your requirements.

Using a load switch IC can be beneficial when reverse current blocking, over-current protection (OCP), over-temperature protection (OTP) or even load fault (open, short, etc) detection is needed as most load switch ICs have these internally. If the application is size-limited then a load switch IC can sometimes be the only way to go as it saves you from placing discrete resistors, MOSFET, and other components.

Define your requirements, go through datasheets, and and pick one that suits best.

Answer (score 0):

> *In general, which solution is preferred when we want to minimize
> quiescent and leakage current?*

There is no right or wrong solution; you sift through various data sheets (several of either device type) and, spend a few hours figuring out which one best suits your specific application.